# Domain Join - The Network Path was not Found

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-firewall

I am unable to join PC's or servers to my domain and am unable to determine the cause...

What have I tried? - Disabled Domain Windows Firewall; Changed Network Adapter from Public to Domain, Changed DNS directly to the Domain Controller (Same Issues), I have Malwarebytes Premium installed but this has not caused issues in the past, The Client is Windows Server 2016 (Unactivated).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the results from the NetSetup.log on the client...

```
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240 NetpDoDomainJoin
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240 NetpDoDomainJoin: using current computer names
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240 NetpDoDomainJoin: NetpGetComputerNameEx(NetBios) returned 0x0
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240 NetpDoDomainJoin: NetpGetComputerNameEx(DnsHostName) returned 0x0
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240 NetpMachineValidToJoin: 'GVSNORTSVR'
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240 NetpMachineValidToJoin: status: 0x0
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240 NetpJoinDomain
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240     HostName: GVSNORTSVR
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240     NetbiosName: GVSNORTSVR
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240     Domain: XXX.co.uk
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240     MachineAccountOU: (NULL)
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240     Account: XXX.co.uk\ADM-LC
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240     Options: 0x27
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240 NetpValidateName: checking to see if 'XXX.co.uk' is valid as type 3 name
03/31/2019 22:16:23:240 NetpValidateName: 'XXX.co.uk' is not a valid NetBIOS domain name: 0x7b
03/31/2019 22:16:23:318 NetpCheckDomainNameIsValid [ Exists ] for 'XXX.co.uk' returned 0x0
03/31/2019 22:16:23:318 NetpValidateName: name 'XXX.co.uk' is valid for type 3
03/31/2019 22:16:23:318 NetpDsGetDcName: trying to find DC in domain 'XXX.co.uk', flags: 0x40001010
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpDsGetDcName: failed to find a DC having account 'GVSNORTSVR$': 0x525, last error is 0x0
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpDsGetDcName: status of verifying DNS A record name resolution for 'XXX-DC.XXX.co.uk': 0x0
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpDsGetDcName: found DC '\\XXX-DC.XXX.co.uk' in the specified domain
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpDsGetDcName returned: 0x0
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpDisableIDNEncoding: using FQDN XXX.co.uk from dcinfo
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpDisableIDNEncoding: DnsDisableIdnEncoding(UNTILREBOOT) on 'XXX.co.uk' succeeded
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpDisableIDNEncoding returned: 0x0
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetUseAdd to \\XXX-DC.XXX.co.uk\IPC$ returned 53
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: status of connecting to dc '\\XXX-DC.XXX.co.uk': 0x35
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Function exits with status of: 0x35
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpResetIDNEncoding: DnsDisableIdnEncoding(RESETALL) on 'XXX.co.uk' returned 0x0
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpResetIDNEncoding on 'XXX.co.uk': 0x0
03/31/2019 22:16:23:774 NetpDoDomainJoin: status: 0x35
```

Here are the results from DCDiag...

```
Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = XXX-DC
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\XXX-DC
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\XXX-DC
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL
         replication problems may cause Group Policy problems.
         ......................... XXX-DC failed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: Replications
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test Replications
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test RidManager
      Starting test: Services
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test SystemLog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... XXX-DC passed test VerifyReferences


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : XXX
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... XXX passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... XXX passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : XXX.co.uk
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         ......................... XXX.co.uk passed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... XXX.co.uk passed test Intersite
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused by the Hyper V Virtual Switch. I had reset all my network adapters and re-sent them back up again. It is now working :)